# java download file always with filename "download"

Tags: java

tried using encode and charset

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
        fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName + ".xlsx", "UTF-8");
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet ; charset=UTF-8"))
                .body(resource);
```

but seems doesn't all work

--------------------------------update response info
[image]

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't work"? What is expected behavior?

Comment: @talex if the fileName is "test.xlsx", expected behavior is I got a downloaded file named test.xlsx, but I got a file named "download.xlsx"

Comment: Are you sure that `fileName` is "test"?

Comment: This happened to me when I used `Chrome`. But in `Firefox`, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

A `Content-Disposition` header that specifies a named attachment needs to have the format

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.extension"
```

Whereas your code is generating

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.extension
```

Whatever browser/client you're using just doesn't understand the second part and so defaults to "download".

Comment: tried set .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= \"" + fileName + "\"")
but doesn't work, do you mean this?

Comment: That should fix it (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)), what client are you using?

Comment: chrome version 71.0

Comment: Do you have special characters (non-ascii) in your filename?

Comment: tried to use Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xlsx" to do a test and still got a download.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help

  `File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application.properties").toURI());
            if (file.exists()) {
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
                try {
                    Files.copy(Paths.get(file.toURI()), response.getOutputStream());
                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }`

Edit : this Worked for me

Comment: @zhuochenshen check now